# Decreasing from the horizontal asymptote

Tags: calculus, limits

The function $f(x) = x^2/(x^2 - x -2)$ has the following [graph](http://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/graph.php?a0=2&a1=x%5E2%2F%28x%5E2%20-%20x%20-2%29&a2=&a3=&a4=1&a5=4&a6=8&a7=1&a8=1&a9=1&b0=500&b1=500&b2=-5&b3=5&b4=-5&b5=5&b6=10&b7=10&b8=5&b9=5&c0=3&c1=0&c2=1&c3=1&c4=1&c5=1&c6=1&c7=0&c8=0&c9=0&d0=1&d1=20&d2=20&d3=0&d4=&d5=&d6=&d7=&d8=&d9=&e0=&e1=&e2=&e3=&e4=14&e5=14&e6=13&e7=12&e8=0&e9=0&f0=0&f1=1&f2=1&f3=0&f4=0&f5=&f6=&f7=&f8=&f9=&g0=&g1=1&g2=1&g3=0&g4=0&g5=0&g6=Y&g7=ffffff&g8=a0b0c0&g9=6080a0&h0=1&z). It has a horizontal asymptote $y=1$. For $x$ less than $-4$, the function is decreasing and its graph is under the asymptote. How is this possible when $\lim_{n \to -\infty} f(x) = 1$? Can a function decrease away from its vertical asymptote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of increasing is
$$
x_1<x_2\implies f(x_1)\ge f(x_1).
$$
As $x$ increases, $f(x)$ decreases. But as $x$ decreases to $-\infty$, $f(x)$ increases to $1$.

Maybe the following example will make things clear. $x^2$ decreases on $(-\infty,0)$, but $\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^2=+\infty$.

Comment: I was looking at it the other way around. I get it now. Thank you!